# list is not callable error while using lambda

Tags: python, list, lambda, key, sorting

I'm currently working on a dataset for a clustering algorithm for which i need to sort the data points in accordance with the distances
Here the data is of type ndarray(n-dimensional array)

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt(fname="irisdataset.txt",delimiter="")

def sort_by_distance(data):

   sum = 0
   for point in data:
        sum += point*point
   return np.sqrt(sum)

sorted(data,key=[lambda x:sort_by_distance(x) for x in data])
```

I get an error here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/abdullah/MainProject/load.py", line 13, in <module>
   sorted(data,key=[lambda x:sort_by_distance(x) for x in data])
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Im new to python so anybody just let me know why i get this error

Comment: You can also flatten your function to `return np.sqrt(sum([i ** 2 for i in data])`

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the error because you're passing a list to the key argument of `sorted`.  But `sorted` expects the key argument to be a *function*.

Without knowing more about `data` (it's structure), it's hard to say how to fix the problem.  My guess is that `data` looks something like this:

```
data = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], ...])
```

and you want to sort each "point" by distance from the origin.  In that case, `np.dot` should be a fine key function.

```
print sorted(data, key=np.dot)
```